# Search model from a select option

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to RoR and I want to make a search for birthdays using a select tag with the months, like:

```
<%= form_tag birthdays_path, :method => 'get' do %>
  <%= select_month (Date.today) %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", :name => nil %>
<% end %>
```

I have a Person model with name and birthday date where I want to do the search and match the month, But I don't know how to get the parameters.

Comment: Did my answer help you in any way?

Answer (score 0):

The model:

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.birthday_month month
    date = Date.current.change(month: month.to_i)
    where("#{table_name}.birthday BETWEEN :from AND :to", 
      { from: date.at_beginning_of_month, to: date.at_end_of_month })
  end
end
```

The controller:

```
class PeopleController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @people = Person.birthday_month(params[:month])
  end
end
```

The responding view (/people/index.js.erb):

```
alert('<%= @people.map(&:name).join(', ') %>')
```

But please also consider that the year is always the **current** year in the search. Otherwise you will have add the year parameter as well or define a default search year.